# Plotting graph in RStudio

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been trying to plot a graph like figure 1 (see below), but I am wondering how can I can the label on the left hand side.

[image]

Below is my R code and my result:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

setwd("/users/ryan/desktop/R_Programming")
moviecounts  <- fread('movie-counts.csv', header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

ggplot(moviecounts[year_rank <=100]) + 
  xlim(2016,1927)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#ffffff", "#afd0df", "#f6a100"))+
  geom_col(aes(fill=result, y=annual_share, x=oscars_year,group = count),    
  colour="#eeeeee")+
  coord_flip()+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Below is the top 20 rows of my dataset:

```
dput(head(moviecounts, 20))

structure(list(movie_name = c("Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope", 
"The Wizard of Oz", "The Godfather", "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back", 
"Jaws", "Psycho", "Casablanca", "Raiders of the Lost Ark", "The Terminator", 
"E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial", "Ghostbusters", "2001: A Space Odyssey", 
"Gone with the Wind", "Back to the Future", "Titanic", "The Shining", 
"Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi", "Jurassic Park", 
"The Matrix", "King Kong"), release_year = c(1977L, 1939L, 1972L, 
1980L, 1975L, 1960L, 1942L, 1981L, 1984L, 1982L, 1984L, 1968L, 
1939L, 1985L, 1997L, 1980L, 1983L, 1993L, 1999L, 1933L), oscars_year = c(1977L, 
1939L, 1972L, 1980L, 1975L, 1960L, 1943L, 1981L, 1984L, 1982L, 
1984L, 1968L, 1939L, 1985L, 1997L, 1980L, 1983L, 1993L, 1999L, 
1933L), ceremony = c("50th", "12th", "45th", "", "48th", "", 
"16th", "54th", "", "55th", "", "", "12th", "", "70th", "", "", 
"", "", ""), result = c("N", "N", "W", "", "N", "", "W", "N", 
"", "N", "", "", "W", "", "W", "", "", "", "", ""), count = c(4965L, 
3291L, 1767L, 1748L, 1570L, 1563L, 1454L, 1396L, 1355L, 1331L, 
1225L, 1176L, 1154L, 1150L, 1128L, 1127L, 1091L, 1081L, 1081L, 
1053L), overall_rank = 1:20, year_rank = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    annual_share = c(0.551789286508113, 0.503441945846719, 0.33695652173913, 
    0.20161476355248, 0.313123254886318, 0.434166666666667, 0.486776029460998, 
    0.226182760855476, 0.143416596104996, 0.164829721362229, 
    0.129657070279424, 0.216017634092579, 0.176533578093927, 
    0.174374526156179, 0.171715634038666, 0.129988465974625, 
    0.164878343660269, 0.160647941744687, 0.142857142857143, 
    0.376879026485326)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7f9e868174e0>)
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you made your issue reproducible by sharing a sample of your **data**? See [how to make a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Simply type `dput(NAME_OF_DATASET)` into the console and copy & paste the output starting with `structure(....` into your post.  If your dataset has a lot of observations you could do `dput(head(NAME_OF_DATASET, 20))` for the first twenty rows of data.

Comment: Besides that one option would be to facet by year (plus some additional styling) which would allow you to map the variable with your (film?) labels on x.

Comment: `geom_text` with some linebreak & proper manual y-Axis would help!
and instead of posting the picture of dput - please copy the out put and paste it here.

Comment: @stefan Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @SinhNguyen Thank you for your advice, I will try gemo_text